Cannot update a component X while rendering a different component Y To locate the bad setState() call inside Y,
I Have an HTML Form with input component in it with validation logic that works (most of the time )
I am trying to update a state isFormValid state in the form to decide if the button should be disabled,
I am trying to achieve this by passing a function that sets that state from the form to the input.
the function takes a ref which is an object with the valid state of the input as an argument and adds it into a set (list) which is kept in its own state . that way the number of items in the set never exceeds the number of inputs  . For some reason I get the error in the title, after doing some research I read that you can pass a function that sets the state to  a child component as long as it is in an event handler which is what is happening in this case, does anyone have an idea why is this occurring?
form



const Contact = () => {
    const [inputStateSet, setInputStateSet] = useState(new Set())

    const addToStateSet = function (stateObj) {
        setInputStateSet((state) => {
            return new Set([...state, stateObj])
        })
    }

    

    const flatArr = []

    inputStateSet.forEach((i) => {
        flatArr.push(i.value)
    })

    const isFormValid = !flatArr.includes(false)

Input

const Input = ({
    addStateFunc,
    validationDesc,
    regex,
    children,
    className,
    type = 'text',
    tag = 'input',
    marginTop,
    ...rest
}) => {
    const onFocus = useContext(onInputFocusContext)
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)
    const [err, setErr] = useState(false)
    const [checkMark, setCheckMark] = useState(false)
    const regExp = new RegExp(regex)
    let timeoutId
    const checkMarkObj = useRef({})
    const Ct = tag
    let timeOutId = useRef()
    const validate = (e) => {
        clearTimeout(timeOutId)
        setErr(false)
        setCheckMark(false)
        e.target.value && setLoading(true)
        timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
            setLoading(false)
            e.target.value && setErr(!regExp.test(e.target.value, 'g'))
            e.target.value &&
                setErr((err) => {
                    !err && setCheckMark(true)
                    return err
                })
            setCheckMark((state) => {
                addStateFunc((checkMarkObj.value = state))
                return state
            })
        }, 1000)
    }

